# Simple pivot of a dataframe is not working

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataframe that I'm working with...

```
Customer_Id ProductName Rating
ABCD             X1      2
EFGH             X2      2
IJKL             Y1      2
MNOP             Y2      2
MNOP             X2      2
```

On pivot,

```
pd.pivot(ratingDF, values = 'Rating', index = 'Customer_Id', columns = 'ProductName')
```

I get an error saying `TypeError: pivot_simple() got multiple values for argument 'index'`

I am very confused as to why this is happening. I am trying to make the customer id the index, the productnames the columns and ratings the content of the dataframe. Any leads will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Don't delete data from your questions, please. Makes it hard for people to understand what's going in.

Comment: I was trying to make it more readable. sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On `v0.20.2`, `df.pivot` works nicely.

```
df.pivot(values='Rating', index='Customer_Id', columns='ProductName').fillna('')

ProductName X1 X2 Y1 Y2
Customer_Id            
ABCD         2         
EFGH            2      
IJKL               2   
MNOP            2     2
```

Actually, there's a subtle difference between `pd.pivot` and `df.pivot`. [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46967843/4909087) covers it nicely.

Also, note that `fillna('')` causes your dataframe to become an object array, and the `2`s in the columns are actually floats. [piRSquared's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967661/simple-pivot-of-a-dataframe-is-not-working/46967725?noredirect=1#comment80883383_46967725) would be to use `pivot_table` with an integral fill value, say, `0`.

```
df.pivot_table(values='Rating', index='Customer_Id', 
                      columns='ProductName', fill_value=0)

ProductName  X1  X2  Y1  Y2
Customer_Id                
ABCD          2   0   0   0
EFGH          0   2   0   0
IJKL          0   0   2   0
MNOP          0   2   0   2
```

---

If none of these options work for you, you might want to upgrade to the latest version. Do that with

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: pd.pivot is a different function, that you can call with distinct arrays, specifically if they're not all columns in a DataFrame (if they are use DataFrame.pivot!)

Comment: @AndyHayden I seriously thought using `pd.pivot` was like calling `ClassName.function(self)` instead of `self.function()`.

Comment: Oh! A combination of these two things worked! @AndyHayden that worked. Thank you so very much.

Comment: By using `fillna('')` after the pivot, all of your `2`s are actually floats in an object array.  Within an object array, they are represented as `2`.  To preserve the int type at the cell level, despite the object array.  You can use `pivot_table` with the `fill_value=''` argument.  `df.pivot_table(values='Rating', index='Customer_Id', columns='ProductName', fill_value='')`

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you! That was informative. Suggestion taken.

Comment: @piRSquared Hmm, I just called `df.values` on the result, they're still floats?

Comment: Yeah!... I ran it myself as well.  Dang, my theory holds up when filling with `0` but not with `''`... I'm kinda weirded out right now.

Comment: @piRSquared usually pivot_table is best choice :) ...That said we should prefer NaN for missing data (not `''`)!

Comment: @piRSquared yes, it works with `0` and that's what I ended up editing my answer with.

Comment: @AndyHayden I'm with you!  I'm just wondering why pandas casts the ints to floats when the array will be of dtype object.  I question whether that was a deliberate choice or an artifact no one has cared to correct.

Comment: @piRSquared the reason, most likely, is it's simply implemented by `.fillna(fill_value)`! Edit: hmmm, but then that doesn't explain the 0 case...

Comment: @piRSquared There ya go: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L118-L119

Comment: @AndyHayden ahh, that's brilliant!  That means that when `fill_value=0` is passed, it **DOES** cast to float, but subsequently downcasts if it is inferred to be appropriate.

Comment: @piRSquared yeah, I had seen but forgotten about 'infer'. I think the object case is something no-one should ever care about, if you're worried about int->float in an object array you're doing something very wrong anyway. "object bad" and all that.

Answer (score 4):

DataFrame's pivot and pd.pivot are slightly different.

[`pd.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) takes separate arrays for index/columns/values, so  you'd call it like:

```
pd.pivot(values=ratingDF['Rating'], index=ratingDF['Customer_Id'], columns=ratingDF['ProductName'])
```

whilst [DataFrame's pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) takes just the column names:

```
# so this is equivalent to the the above
ratingDF.pivot(values='Rating', index='Customer_Id', columns='ProductName')
```

*Note: if you have missing data,  or want to do more aggregation consider [`.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).*

Comment: Really? Is that how it works? I assumed it'd take string values and look for these column in the passed dataframe object. I must say. Thanks for teaching me something.